# Excel - Automatically changing to all-bold or no-bold on save

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a series of steps in Excel. The workbook is quite extensive, with 15 tabs all having different versions of the same steps. I use these steps as a process to write novels. So for example, step one might be to define character A. Step 2 might be to find a flaw for character A. And so on. There are a few formulas, but for the most part it's just lots of text.

**The problem:** I open the majority of the steps with a single bold line, summing up what you do. I then follow that line with a non-bold detailed description. Both the bold and non-bold are in the same cell. An example would look like this:

> **List the known characters.** Subcharacters are supporting characters. Therefore you should start with the main characters, which are being supported, and any additional characters you already know of.

This has worked perfectly fine for a long time. However, I have noticed that when I open the workbook with another program (like Openoffice), or on another computer (like my laptop), some of the data seems to get corrupted. The cells go to all-bold or no-bold. A few are formatted correctly, but most are messed up.

I cleaned part of it up yesterday and saved it, but upon opening the workbook back up today, things are back to the way the were. In addition, some new cells I had added yesterday are now all-bold as well.

I had opened the workbook on my laptop during the previous week, but the first time this happened is five days after I moved it back to my computer from my laptop. I have since added data with no problem, but yesterday was the first time I actually added rows.

**What's causing this? Can I stop it?** It's a relatively easy fix (if time-consuming) but I'd prefer to spend my time writing, and not cleaning up Excel. I am using Excel 2016.

Comment: I'm pretty certain that being able to mix formatting types in a single cell involves an Excel-specific implementation. Once the workbook has been opened in another app, all bets are off. I suggest going back to a version of the wb before opening in another app.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a very sophisticated system you developed there, impressive! 
Whenever I transfer spreadsheets between excel, openoffice, and libreoffice, there is always some kind of change of formatting. Has to do with the different ways the different applications read and deal with it I assume. And it sometimes takes a while to convert the document, and then you have to adjust it, save it in a new format if you want to open it again... it's just a headache. Frankly, excel itself is not very friendly and intuitive for lots of text formatting stuff. I would consider trying to do this all in MS word, perhaps using fillable fields, or perhaps in a fillable PDF form. Would be nicer for writing, but you would lose the formulas. There is probably an auto-fill option though.

And/or, if you don't have excel on all your computers and you don't absolutely need to use it, perhaps consider always opening this document with open office, on any computer you go to, because it is free to install on all of them, and then you maintain consistency. Alternatively, set up a usb drive with portable openoffice or libreoffice on it, and have the document on it too, and then you don't need to install multiple times; just work off the usb drive.

Final suggestion, an online doc editor like google docs would allow you to always open the doc in the same way and app, but you have to have an internet connection.

On another thought, why not separate the bold and unboldened text into separate cells? If it doesn't affect your functionality that much, perhaps this could be the solution.

Comment: Do you know why Excel changes things back even after I've corrected it and there's no other computer/program involved?

Answer (score 0):

it's very common phenomenon,, whenever data created, open in other software similar even,, discards some of the features.

So that converter applications are available. ☺
Like Word to PDF. ☺

Sometimes if few Fonts are not available in other Computers the similar software rejects Formatting.

Comment: Thomas, it's difficult to come to conclusions spontaneously, please specify what corrections Excel rejects.

Comment: I believe I specify what Excel is doing in my OP here: "upon opening the workbook back up today, things are back to the way the were. In addition, some new cells I had added yesterday are now all-bold as well." When I change the cells back to the way they should be (starting with bold then continuing in non-bold), when I open the workbook back up it has reverted to all-bold or no-bold.

Comment: Thomas ,, Ive few suggestions,, better you apply auto save so in regular interval Excel will save the modifications. And at last use Save as and save one other copy of the file. Then open both Old & New Version and see whether changes have been accepted or not.

Comment: Thomas ,, any error Message you have ever revived ,, like Not Save the File ,,!